# bash: recursively shorten directory name to first 10 characters

Tags: bash

I need to recursively rename all subdirectories to the first 10 characters of the original subdirectory name.

For example, the below directory:

```
/Documents/super-long-folder-name/other-folder-name/
```

would be renamed to:

```
/Documents/super-long/other-fold/
```

I have found a way to rename files to the first 10 characters of the original file name, but now I need to do this for directories.

To recursively rename the file names, I installed the perl rename function: `brew install rename` and then executed the code below:

```
find . -path '????????????????????*' -exec rename 's/^(.{10}).*(\..*)$/$1$2/' * {} \;
```

The above code finds files with file paths greater than 20 characters, then renames the file to the first 10 characters of the original file name.

Now I am trying to find a similar solution that would allow me to do this to *directory* names.

Thank you in advance for any insight you might have!

Comment: You might interest yourself in `-depth` option to `find`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

finddir="."

# calculate the max depth
depth=1
while IFS= read -r -d "" dir; do
    str="${dir//[^\/]}"
    if (( depth < ${#str} )); then
        depth=${#str}
    fi
done < <(find "$finddir" -type d -links 2 -print0)

# change long dirnames by starting with depth=1 incrementally
for (( i=1; i<=depth; i++ )); do
    while IFS= read -r -d "" dir; do
        stem=${dir%/*}      # parent dir
        leaf=${dir##*/}     # current target dir
        if (( ${#leaf} > 10 )); then
            short=${leaf:0:10}
            if [[ -d $stem/$short ]]; then
                echo "$stem/$short exists. $stem/$leaf unchanged."
            else
                mv -- "$stem/$leaf" "$stem/$short"
#               echo mv "$stem/$leaf" "$stem/$short"
            fi
        fi
    done < <(find "$finddir" -type d -mindepth "$i" -maxdepth "$i" -print0)
done
```

The difficult point is the pathnames dynamically change during the execution and
pathnames given by `find` may differ from actual (renamed) pathnames.

My approach is:

- to calculate the maximum depth in advance.
- to iterate into deeper directory starting with depth=1 until depth=maximum_depth calculated above.

Hope this helps.